# Craft CMS Log Rotation

Tags: admin, logs

Does Craft have somewhere where I can setup log rotation for the craft.log file, or do admins have to manage that manually?

Answer (score 4):

Craft will automatically 'rotate' logs into new files as each current file reaches the maximum size (~1MB).

This is why, if you look in `/craft/storage/runtime/logs`, you may see `craft.log`, `craft.1.log`, `craft.2.log`, etc.

(I *think* Craft keeps a max of 5 files around before rotating them off into the ether.)

At present, the max size, naming convention, and max log file count, are all *not* configurable. (To my great chagrin.)

If you want to rename/archive logs for your own purposes, you'll have to create your own workflow for that, either by scripting it and running it as a cron job, or by using a third-party aggregation/archival service such as [*Papertrail*](https://papertrailapp.com/).

Comment: Probably also worth adding a [feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com/) to make those settings configurable.

Comment: Hmmm. Our craft log is like 300MB. Seems like the rotating isn't working correctly in our setup. Maybe it has to do with being on IIS.

Comment: Sounds like maybe a bug; Email support about that one.

Comment: I can confirm that another website on IIS has larger than 1MB log files.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do with the logs, if you're on a *nix server, [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) is built into most systems.

Do something like:

```
/home/*user*/craft/storage/runtime/logs/*.log {

  weekly
  dateext
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
```

}

... which would rotate and gzip the logs after a week and append the date. There's a billion options in there including e-mailing you copies or moving them to different directories (like an archive). On Ubuntu/Debian, check out `/etc/logrotate.d/` for examples.